# Function Value hints python

Tags: python

I have couple of functions on a python code and I want to use value hints. This function does not give me any errors:

```
def function1(self, a: int, b: int = 0):
```

But when I want to add another parameter to the function it gives me an error:

```
def function1(self, a: int, b: int = 0, c: int):

SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument
```

Do you know if there is any way to solve this, so that I can have a non-default argument following a default argument?

Comment: How do you expect to _call_ that, provide a value for `c` but let `b` take the default? If you want `c` to be keyword-only see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37829651/3001761, but this isn't related to the type hints - you'd have the same problem without them.

Comment: What do you think is a „Value hint“? In Python, default values and type homes are mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

The error says: you can not make argument with no default value in parameter. that is a syntax rule from python.
to make it works just add default values like this:

```
def function1(self, a: int, b: int = 0, c: int = 0):
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, arguments with default values must follow arguments with required values.

Try rewriting as `def function1(self, a: int, c: int, b: int = 0,):`

You can still call it by doing `function1(self, a=a_val, b=b_val, c=c_val)`